# Minimum Effective Dose of Exercise for Cognitive Enhancement

Tags: exercise, exercise-frequency

Given the exercise goal of enhancing cognitive function (higher energy levels, better memory and/or better reasoning skills), what is the Minimum Effective Dose of exercise required for a young adult (ages 20-35)? As in, what is the minimum amount of time spent exercising (with no constraints on spacing, types {cardio vs strength} or intensity) per week that has the maximum amount of cognitive benefits?

**Notes:**

- I am using the term Minimum Effective Dose to mean "the point of maximum benefit and minimal cost", as taken from "The 4 Hour Body".
- "[Is there such a thing as a minimum amount of exercise per week?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13874/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-minimum-amount-of-exercise-per-week)" addressed the idea of a general minimum of exercise, but it seemed to only target general health.
- [This article](http://brainblogger.com/2015/02/04/can-physical-exercise-improve-cognitive-abilities/) (mentions a U-shaped curve) and [this product](http://www.bodbot.com/Cognitive_Health.html) seem to insinuate that there is a specific exercise regimen for cognitive enhancement, but they're not very convincing.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27474154 you may start reading this 2016 review article